# Process single channel image by glsl texture

Tags: c++, opengl, glsl

Sharpening codes developed by glsl([source](http://igortrindade.wordpress.com/2010/04/23/fun-with-opengl-and-shaders/))

```
uniform sampler2D sampler;

uniform vec2 offset[9];

uniform int kernel[9];

void main()
{
vec4 sum = vec4(0.0);
int i;

for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
vec4 color = texture2D(sampler, gl_TexCoord[0].st + offset[i]);
sum += color * kernel[i];
}

gl_FragColor = sum
}
```

works on 4 channels image, what if I want it to work on a single channel?
I can't find something like vec1, do I have other solution rather than transform
a single channel images to a 3 channels image?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Anytime you access a non-shadow sampler, regardless of how many channels it's actual format has, you will get a *g*vec4 (where `g` can be nothing for float, `i` for integer, and `u` for unsigned integer).

Any values that aren't in the texture's image format (ie: if you ask for the green component from a texture that has only red) will be filled in with zeros. Unless the component you ask for is alpha, in which case you get 1.

Don't forget: you can always create new values with the [texture object's swizzle setting](http://www.opengl.org/wiki/Texture#Swizzle_mask). So with a simple swizzle mask, you can make a texture that only stores 1 value look like it stores 4:

```
GLint swizzleMask[] = {GL_RED, GL_RED, GL_RED, GL_RED};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

This broadcasts the red channel of the texture to all 4 components, just like the old GL_INTENSITY texture. You can swap them around so it only comes out of the alpha:

```
GLint swizzleMask[] = {GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO, GL_ZERO, GL_RED};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

Or maybe you want all the other channels to be 1:

```
GLint swizzleMask[] = {GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_ONE, GL_RED};
glTexParameteriv(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_SWIZZLE_RGBA, swizzleMask);
```

Answer (score 3):

The sampler object is always the same. Just use the first `n` channels of `color` (e.g. `color.r` for a single channel `GL_RED` texture).

Answer (score 2):

you can use 
`texture2D(sampler, gl_TexCoord[0].st + offset[i]).r` to get the red channel or g / b for the others (a for alpha)

on the other hand you can use a float value for sum like

```
sum += texture2D(sampler, gl_TexCoord[0].st + offset[i]).r ;
```